# Should a base object with no member variables be serialized when using boost::serialization?

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

Do I need to serialize a base object (e.g. an interface) with no members?

```
class Base {
    template <typename A> void serialize(A& a, unsigned int v) {}
};

class Derived: public Base {
    template <typename A> void serialize(A& a, unsigned int v) {
        // Should I do this?
        archive & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
    }
};
```

It seems like this is unnecessary boilerplate and incurs an additional dependency from boost::serialization on the base class, but at the same time if somebody would add a member to the base class later, it would be difficult, because the whole hierarchy would need to be changed.

Comment: I am not sure, what if you serialize a base pointer?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it won't work without without serializing base object. Can you make it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

For serialization of base pointers you need the Base::serialize.